# Ajax query without reconnecting to database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I've written webpage to display cars on a map. All page refreshing processes are done using XMLHttpRequest. All database querys, despite those when the page is loading, are done with the same approach. 
Problem is that when i send XMLHttpRequest i need to open new connection to my database. Page is refreshing every few seconds and has to refresh a lot of objects. It generates a lot of new connections to my database.

What I want to do is to open mysql connection only once when i start my page and use this connection in all this Ajax querys.

**Is it possible?**

(edited)

Base on yours answers I've been searching for persistent connection and Node.js but I still have problem understanding it. ***Can someone post an example of persistent connection and XHR?***

Please help me understand Http Connection Lifecycle. What happens when i write mysql_connect? When does connection close? What about mysql_pconnect? How does open connection look from server perspective?

Comment: Use a persistent connection, or a singleton class or store the data you got once in session and fetch next time from the session if its not frequently updated.

Comment: You could use a persistent connection yes - although if you're not closing your connection after each use, you're more vulnerable to attacks. Plus, it may put more strain on your server to have large persistent connections open, as apposed to many small but quickly closed ones (but the speed comparison is worth testing I suppose).

Comment: If it's possible, don't use PHP for this. There are better platforms more suitable for your approach, like NodeJS, for example.

Comment: like @MartinHeralecký said, fot this kind of web/app/game is much better something like websockets. Easy to use with nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You cannot do this with PHP without tricks.**

Every time you ask for a webpage powered by PHP witch query a database (like MySQL), PHP need to "open" a connection, query the DB, close the connection and close itself.

... but there is some tricks :

**1 : Chunked solution**

Do a `XMLHttpRequest` request on PHP script with an loop (30 seconds can be good). Each loop execution you can write some datas to be returned on the ajax query. After the loop is over, retry the query (it will do one connection each 30 seconds).

This solution is called chunked data. You return "partial" response each loop and the ajax query parse each chunk of data. This require to have a PHP and the Webserver with no buffering cache.

**2 : Daemon solution**

You can have a "background" PHP script working as daemon for querying the database with one thread (or more than one ?) witch make some static files (containing json ?) and query the static file with `XMLHttpRequest`.